# Immediate isolation level sqlite Python

Tags: python, sqlite

What does the `immediate` isolation level in Python sqlite3 correspond to? As far as i can tell, what it does is not really documented in the documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions

Would i be right in assuming it places a `reserved lock` on the database? [https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#reserved_lock]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it immediately (tries to) grab a reserved lock, as opposed to waiting until you execute a write operation.

Python just passes it to SQLite's [`BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).